# Ruby Warrior Level 8 - my solution not working?

Tags: ruby

I cannot determine why this is not working. I throw it in irb and it works fine.. Please let me know if you see the issue

My Code:

```
class Player
  def play_turn(warrior)
    @warrior = warrior
    @turn ||= 0

    puts @warrior.look

    if @warrior.look.include?("Wizard")
      @warrior.shoot!
```

Output of puts which is an Array:

```
nothing
Captive
Wizard
```

For some reason it will not do the shoot, this if statement returns false.. Thanks!

Comment: Just because you don't understand the code in the question doesn't make it "off topic." Leave open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@warrior.look` returns an **array of `Space` objects and not `string`s**. Only `puts` converts them to `string` that is why your `.include?("Wizard")` is not working.

So you can convert the `Space` objects to string before your  `.include?("Wizard")` or you need a condition which works on `Space` object like using the `Space#enemy?` or `Space#unit` methods:

```
if @warrior.look.any? { |space| space.enemy? }
      @warrior.shoot!
```

Comment: Here's a gist of all solutions: https://gist.github.com/GantMan/8924331

Also, I'm doing a blog post on walkthroughs for it :) 
http://www.iconoclastlabs.com/blog/ruby-warrior-walkthrough-part-1